# ANTLR: Is there a simple example?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I'd like to get started with ANTLR, but after spending a few hours reviewing the examples at the [antlr.org](http://www.antlr.org/) site, I still can't get a clear understanding of the grammar to Java process.

Is there some simple example, something like a four-operations calculator implemented with ANTLR going through the parser definition and all the way to the Java source code?

Comment: I've just posted the first parts of a video tutorial on ANTLR. See http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut Hope you find it helpful!

Comment: The best answer for ANTLR 4 is buy Parr's book "The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference."

Answer (score 480, accepted):

**Note**: this answer is for **ANTLR3**! If you're looking for an **ANTLR4** example, then this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610183/if-else-statements-in-antlr-using-listeners) demonstrates how to create a simple expression parser, and evaluator using **ANTLR4**.

---

You first create a grammar. Below is a small grammar that you can use to evaluate expressions that are built using the 4 basic math operators: +, -, * and /. You can also group expressions using parenthesis.

Note that this grammar is just a very basic one: it does not handle unary operators (the minus in: -1+9) or decimals like .99 (without a leading number), to name just two shortcomings. This is just an example you can work on yourself.

Here's the contents of the grammar file **Exp.g**:

```
grammar Exp;

/* This will be the entry point of our parser. */
eval
    :    additionExp EOF
    ;

/* Addition and subtraction have the lowest precedence. */
additionExp
    :    multiplyExp 
         ( '+' multiplyExp 
         | '-' multiplyExp
         )* 
    ;

/* Multiplication and division have a higher precedence. */
multiplyExp
    :    atomExp
         ( '*' atomExp 
         | '/' atomExp
         )* 
    ;

/* An expression atom is the smallest part of an expression: a number. Or 
   when we encounter parenthesis, we're making a recursive call back to the
   rule 'additionExp'. As you can see, an 'atomExp' has the highest precedence. */
atomExp
    :    Number
    |    '(' additionExp ')'
    ;

/* A number: can be an integer value, or a decimal value */
Number
    :    ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

/* We're going to ignore all white space characters */
WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

*(Parser rules start with a lower case letter, and lexer rules start with a capital letter)*

After creating the grammar, you'll want to generate a parser and lexer from it. Download the [ANTLR jar](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-3.2.jar) and store it in the same directory as your grammar file.

Execute the following command on your shell/command prompt:

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Exp.g
```

It should not produce any error message, and the files **ExpLexer.java**, **ExpParser.java** and **Exp.tokens** should now be generated.

To see if it all works properly, create this test class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class ANTLRDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("12*(5-6)");
        ExpLexer lexer = new ExpLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ExpParser parser = new ExpParser(tokens);
        parser.eval();
    }
}
```

and compile it:

```
// *nix/MacOS
javac -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo.java

// Windows
javac -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo.java
```

and then run it:

```
// *nix/MacOS
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo

// Windows
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo
```

If all goes well, nothing is being printed to the console. This means the parser did not find any error. When you change `"12*(5-6)"` into `"12*(5-6"` and then recompile and run it, there should be printed the following:

```
line 0:-1 mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting ')'
```

Okay, now we want to add a bit of Java code to the grammar so that the parser actually does something useful. Adding code can be done by placing `{` and `}` inside your grammar with some plain Java code inside it.

But first: all parser rules in the grammar file should return a primitive double value. You can do that by adding  `returns [double value]` after each rule:

```
grammar Exp;

eval returns [double value]
    :    additionExp
    ;

additionExp returns [double value]
    :    multiplyExp 
         ( '+' multiplyExp 
         | '-' multiplyExp
         )* 
    ;

// ...
```

which needs little explanation: every rule is expected to return a double value. Now to "interact" with the return value `double value` (which is NOT inside a plain Java code block `{...}`) from inside a code block, you'll need to add a dollar sign in front of `value`:

```
grammar Exp;

/* This will be the entry point of our parser. */
eval returns [double value]                                                  
    :    additionExp { /* plain code block! */ System.out.println("value equals: "+$value); }
    ;
    
// ...
```

Here's the grammar but now with the Java code added:

```
grammar Exp;

eval returns [double value]
    :    exp=additionExp {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;

additionExp returns [double value]
    :    m1=multiplyExp       {$value =  $m1.value;} 
         ( '+' m2=multiplyExp {$value += $m2.value;} 
         | '-' m2=multiplyExp {$value -= $m2.value;}
         )* 
    ;

multiplyExp returns [double value]
    :    a1=atomExp       {$value =  $a1.value;}
         ( '*' a2=atomExp {$value *= $a2.value;} 
         | '/' a2=atomExp {$value /= $a2.value;}
         )* 
    ;

atomExp returns [double value]
    :    n=Number                {$value = Double.parseDouble($n.text);}
    |    '(' exp=additionExp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;

Number
    :    ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

and since our `eval` rule now returns a double, change your ANTLRDemo.java into this:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class ANTLRDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("12*(5-6)");
        ExpLexer lexer = new ExpLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ExpParser parser = new ExpParser(tokens);
        System.out.println(parser.eval()); // print the value
    }
}
```

Again (re) generate a fresh lexer and parser from your grammar (1), compile all classes (2) and run ANTLRDemo (3):

```
// *nix/MacOS
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Exp.g   // 1
javac -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo.java      // 2
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo            // 3

// Windows
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Exp.g   // 1
javac -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo.java      // 2
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar ANTLRDemo            // 3
```

and you'll now see the outcome of the expression `12*(5-6)` printed to your console!

Again: this is a very brief explanation. I encourage you to browse the [ANTLR wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/ANTLR+3+Wiki+Home) and read some tutorials and/or play a bit with what I just posted.

Good luck!

EDIT:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042353/extending-simple-antlr-grammer-to-support-input-variables) shows how to extend the example above so that a `Map<String, Double>` can be provided that holds variables in the provided expression.

To get this code working with a current version of Antlr (June 2014) I needed to make a few changes. `ANTLRStringStream` needed to become `ANTLRInputStream`, the returned value needed to change from `parser.eval()` to `parser.eval().value`, and I needed to remove the `WS` clause at the end, because attribute values such as `$channel` are no longer allowed to appear in lexer actions.

Comment: Where does the implemenations of `parser.eval()` happen? That isn't clear HERE or on the ANTLR3 Wiki!

Comment: @Jarrod, err, sorry, I don't really understand you. `eval` is a parser rule which returns a `double`. So there is an `eval()` method you can call on an instance of an `ExpParser`, just as I demonstrated in the `ANTLRDemo.main(...)`. After generating a lexer/parser, simply open the file `ExpParser.java` and you'll see that there's an `eval()` method returning a `double`.

Comment: @Bart I've been researching this for a week -- this is the first example that was actually detailed and complete enough to work the first time and that I think I understand. I had almost given up. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

[ANTLR mega tutorial](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial) by Gabriele Tomassetti is very helpful

It has grammar examples, examples of visitors in different languages (Java, JavaScript, C# and Python) and many other things. Highly recommended.

EDIT: other useful articles by Gabriele Tomassetti on ANTLR

- [Getting started with ANTLR in C#](https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-with-antlr-in-csharp/)
- [Getting Started with ANTLR in
  C++](https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-antlr-cpp/)

Comment: Great tutorial!

Comment: Antlr now has cpp also as the target language. Are there any tutorials with example on cpp?

Comment: The same guy made a tutorial for ANTLR in C++ https://tomassetti.me/getting-started-antlr-cpp/ I'm guessing you're going to find what you're looking for in here or in the mega tutorial

Answer (score 7):

For Antlr 4 the java code generation process is below:-

```
java -cp antlr-4.5.3-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool Exp.g
```

Update your jar name in classpath accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

version 4.7.1 was slightly different : 
for import:

```
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
```

for the main segment - note the CharStreams:

```
CharStream in = CharStreams.fromString("12*(5-6)");
ExpLexer lexer = new ExpLexer(in);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
ExpParser parser = new ExpParser(tokens);
```

Answer (score 3):

At https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr you'll find an ANTLR java library with some useful helper classes and a few complete examples. It's ready to be used with maven and if you like eclipse and maven.

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/com/bitplan/exp/Exp.g4

is a simple Expression language that can do multiply and add operations.
https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/antlr/TestExpParser.java has the corresponding unit tests for it.

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/blob/master/src/main/antlr4/com/bitplan/iri/IRIParser.g4 is an IRI parser that has been split into the three parts:

1. parser grammar
2. lexer grammar
3. imported LexBasic grammar

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/antlr/TestIRIParser.java
has the unit tests for it.

Personally I found this the most tricky part to get right. See http://wiki.bitplan.com/index.php/ANTLR_maven_plugin

https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/tree/master/src/main/antlr4/com/bitplan/expr

contains three more examples that have been created for a performance issue of ANTLR4 in an earlier version. In the meantime this issues has been fixed as the testcase https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.antlr/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/antlr/TestIssue994.java shows.