# Why does my grammar work for operators like *, -, /, but not +?

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I'm creating a grammar right now and I had to get rid of left recursion, and it seems work for everything except the addition operator.

Here is the related part of my grammar:

```
SUBTRACT: '-';
PLUS: '+';
DIVIDE: '/';
MULTIPLY: '*';

expr: 
      (
        IDENTIFIER 
        | INTEGER 
        | STRING 
        | TRUE 
        | FALSE
      )
      (
        PLUS expr 
        | SUBTRACT expr 
        | MULTIPLY expr 
        | DIVIDE expr 
        | LESS_THAN expr 
        | LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL expr 
        | EQUALS expr
      )*
      ;

INTEGER: ('0'..'9')*;
IDENTIFIER: ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')*;
```

Then when I try to do something like

```
x*1
```

It work's perfectly. However when I try to do something like

```
x+1
```

I get an error saying:

> MismatchedTokenException: mismatched input '+' expecting '\u001C'

I've been at this for a while but don't get why it works with *, -, and /, but not +. I have the exact same code for all of them.

**Edit:** If I reorder it and put SUBTRACT above PLUS, the + symbol will now work but the - symbol won't. Why would antlr care about the order of stuff like that?

Comment: What are IDENTIFIER, INTEGER, etc. defined to be?

Comment: does your INTEGER expression contain a `+` in it?

Comment: Whoops, I just added what INTEGER and IDENTIFIER are in the question. I believe I have all the related things in there now. There is no + in the INTEGER rule.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding left recursion (in an expression grammar) is usually done like this:

```
grammar Expr;

parse
  :  expr EOF
  ;

expr
  :  equalityExpr
  ;

equalityExpr
  :  relationalExpr (('==' | '!=') relationalExpr)*
  ;

relationalExpr
  :  additionExpr (('>=' | '<=' | '>' | '<') additionExpr)*
  ;

additionExpr
  :  multiplyExpr (('+'| '-') multiplyExpr)*
  ;

multiplyExpr
  :  atom (('*' | '/') atom)*
  ;

atom
  :  IDENTIFIER
  |  INTEGER
  |  STRING
  |  TRUE
  |  FALSE
  |  '(' expr ')'
  ;

// ... lexer rules ...
```

For example, the input `A+B+C` would be parsed as follows:

[image]

Also see this related answer: [ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example/1932664#1932664)

Comment: Thanks. I'd first misread something, which eventually lead to finding and fixing the bug in my own grammar, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making a new rule for the part at the end that I made from removing left recursion:

```
expr: 
      (
        IDENTIFIER 
        | INTEGER 
        | STRING 
        | TRUE 
        | FALSE
      ) lr*
      ;

lr:         PLUS expr 
        | SUBTRACT expr 
        | MULTIPLY expr 
        | DIVIDE expr 
        | LESS_THAN expr 
        | LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL expr 
        | EQUALS expr;
```

Comment: This is not the way to go: the expression `2*3+4` is being parsed as `(2*(3+4))` (i.e. the `+` now has a higher precedence than `*`).