# Compile a java program given in a String

Tags: java, compilation

I want to conduct a little experiment, and generate a java program in a String (the experiment is itself in Java).

Now I want to test whether it compiles or not. How do I take a `String` object in Java and see whether it is legal Java code?

**Clarification:**

```
String prog = "public interface B {public void speak();}"
boolean doesItCompile = ???
```

Comment: please write some algorithm, i am unable to get what you are talking about.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind (since it's fairly obvious): write strings to a .java file. And then try to compile it using `Runtime.exec`. And then read the standard output and error streams. But there might be an easier way...

Comment: Try to use systemcall to write a file and run 'javac'.
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac MyClass.java");

Answer (score 6):

You should look into [javax.tools.JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). see [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`JavaCompiler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).  The API documentation provides an example of how to create a number of compilation tasks and invoke call on each one.  The [`call`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.CompilationTask.html#call%28%29) method returns a boolean to indicate whether each compilation attempt was successful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a compiler [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html).

Example can be seen [here](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/73-the-java-60-compiler-api-4.html):

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to verify if the content of the String is legal Java code then you should have a look at antlr. It can be used to parse a java source file and create an abstract syntax tree. If that fails, then the input is not valid.

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example) shows a working example with a simple grammar. You'd have to use the Java grammar instead.