# Conversion of CharSequence to maths expression

Tags: java, android

In my App i have two TextViews one contains an expression eg. 3 + 4 =

And the second contains an answer eg. 7

How would i go about turning this into a valid maths expression so the app could calculate it and return the answer as an int?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the complexity of the expressions you expect in your TextViews, you might need to construct a parser/interpreter for them. If that's the case, I heartily recommend [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/). For more information about using ANTLR on Android, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596609/antlr-and-android).

Another parser generator that I know of is [JavaCC](http://java.net/projects/javacc), but ANTLR is a lot more flexible and powerful.