# (Android) ANTLRStringStream throwing exception

Tags: android, stream, antlr

I've been trying to get ANTLR-3.5-complete.jar to work on an Android app, but I can't get it to work! Bart Kiers's answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594966/android-antlr-make-not-working-properly) has helped me a lot, but I still can't get it to work.

I'm trying to make a Button that, when clicked, will validate whether the text in the EditText view is correct according to my **grammar.g**, but it doesn't matter whether the text I input is correct or not, my app always crashes when I click the button while instantiating the ANTLRStringStream. Here's what I have:

```
public void onClickVerify(View v) throws TypeNotPresentException {
    String source = "foobar";
    Log.e("TestDebug", "Instantiating views");
    TextView out = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    EditText in = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    try {
        Log.e("TestDebug", "Getting source from EditText");
        source = in.getText().toString();
        Log.e("TestDebug", "source = " + source);
        Log.e("TestDebug", "Instantiating stream");
        ANTLRStringStream stream = new ANTLRStringStream(source);
        Log.e("TestDebug", "Instantiating lexer");
        grammarLexer lexer = new grammarLexer(stream);
        Log.e("TestDebug", "Instantiating parser");
        grammarParser parser = new grammarParser(
                new BufferedTokenStream(lexer));
        Log.e("TestDebug", "Applying rule to parser");
        out.setText(source + " = " + !parser.failed());
    } catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        out.setText("Exception caught");
    }
}
```

And here's what I see in the logs:

- Instantiating views
- Getting source from EditText
- source = test33
- Instantiating stream

And then the "Unfortunately, TestAntlrApp has stopped." window pops up.

EDIT: Here's more of my logcat.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream
at com.test.antlr.MainActivity.onClickVerify(MainActivity.java:89)
```

Something about not finding the class ANTLRStringStream class? However there seems to be no errors/warnings in the code and I can even see the class's hierarchy.

Comment: What happens if you use the ANTLR version mentioned in that previous answer?

Comment: And what exception is thrown? Replace your `catch` with this and post what you see on your log-cat: `catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("TestDebug", "Exception caught: ", e);
    }`

Comment: @BartKiers I'll try changing the ANTLR version and see what happens!
I changed the `catch` but the code never gets excecuted. It crashes within the `try` without ever reaching `catch`, so my log output remains the same.

Edit: v3.3 seems to have been removed from the ANTLR website. I can only find v3.5.

Comment: The website changed from antlr.org to antlr3.org. So the link is now: http://www.antlr3.org/download/antlr-3.3-complete.jar

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks! I tried it with v3.3 but I still get the same problem. The app simply dies when instantiating `stream`... I can't find a possible explanation as to why this could be happening.

Comment: A `NoClassDefFoundError` occurs when a certain class, `org.antlr.runtime.ANTLRStringStream` in your case, cannot be found by the (Dalvik) JVM. It seems it is not properly packaged inside your APK. Hard to say more about it since I can't see exactly how you're building and running your APK.

Comment: Alright, I worked it out! Turns out I'm not supposed to add my libraries to the Build Path using Eclipse's conventional way of doing it. Instead, I have to put it inside the "libs" folder for it to be packed within the .apk. If I simply add it to the build path, it's omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a recent ADT update, you can't just add external libraries to the Build Path using Eclipse's conventional way of doing it. Instead, you have to put it inside the **libs** folder for it to be packed within the .apk. If you simply add it to the build path, it will be ignored when building your .apk.

Symptom : The app was not recognizing external library classes.

Solution : Put the .jar file in the **libs** folder.