# Cannot intrepret ANTLRWorks output

Tags: java, antlr, antlrworks

I am using the following simple grammar to get an understanding of ANTLR.

```
grammar Example;
options {
language=Java;
}

ID  : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INT : '0'..'9'+
    ;
PLUS    :   '+';


ADDNUM  :   
    INT PLUS INT;

prog    :    ADDNUM;
```

When I try running the grammar in ANTLRWorks for the input `1+2`, I get the following error in the console:

> [16:54:08] Interpreting... [16:54:08] problem matching token at 2:0
>   NoViableAltException(' '@[1:1: Tokens : ( ID | INT | PLUS | ADDNUM);])

Can anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably didn't indicate `prog` as the starting rule in ANTLRWorks. If you do, it all goes okay.

But you really shouldn't create a lexer rule that matches an expression like you do in `ADDNUM`: this should be a parser rule:

```
grammar Example;

prog    : addExpr EOF;
addExpr : INT PLUS INT;
ID      : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*;
INT     : '0'..'9'+;
PLUS    : '+';
```

---

### ANTLR rules

There are no strict rules when to use parser-, lexer- or fragment rules, but here's what they're usually used for:

#### lexer rules

A lexer rule is usually the smallest part of a language (a string, a numbers, an identifier, a comment, etc.). Trying to create a lexer rule from input like `1+2` causes problems because:

- if you ever want to extract something meaningful from that token (evaluate it, for example), you need to split the contents of that token because after creating 1 token from it, the text from the entire expression is "glued" together;
- you run into problems when there are white-space in between it: `1 +   2`.

The expression `1+2` are three tokens: `INT`, `PLUS` and another `INT`.

#### fragment rules

A fragment rule is used when you don't want this rule to ever because a "real" token. For example, take the following lexer rules:

```
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
FLOAT : '0'..'9'+ '.' '0'..'9'+; 
INT   : '0'..'9'+;
```

In the rules above, you're using `'0'..'9'` four times, so you could place that in a separate rule

```
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | DIGIT)*
FLOAT : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+; 
INT   : DIGIT+;
DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

But you don't want to ever create a `DIGIT` token: you only want the `DIGIT` to be used by other lexer rules. In that case, you can create a `fragment` rule:

```
ID    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | DIGIT)*
FLOAT : DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+; 
INT   : DIGIT+;
fragment DIGIT : '0'..'9';
```

This will make sure there will never be a `DIGIT` token: and can therefor never use this in your parser  rule(s)!

#### parser rules

Parser rules glue the tokens together: they make sure the language is [syntactic valid (a.k.a. parsing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). To emphasize, parser rules can use other parser rules or lexer rules, but **not** fragment rules.

---

Also see: [ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It worked fine after your suggested changes. I am having a hard time understanding what should be parser rules, lexer rules and how does `fragment` fit into these rules. Can you please point me to a resource that would help me understand these terms and how to implement them in ANTLR?

Comment: Thank you Bart. Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: @darkie15, see my edited answer: hope that clarifies it (a bit).