# ANTLR Floating Point and Int returns in grammar

Tags: antlr, grammar

I am working on creating a language with ANTLR, and started a base language with the expr.g example.  I am using ANTLR 3.  I am ready to work on more data types than ints, and after looking around, I found Bart Kiers' wonderful example for floats, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example/1932664#1932664).

In his example, he has the expression return float, however, this means that it doesn't return int.  I am confused on how to have a return rule allow for more than one return type?  I was thinking I could make a combined "number" type that incorporated ints and floats and return that, but then of course I run into the issue that within Java I have to return an int or a float specifically.  Do I have to have two versions of the expression code, one for each data type?  I would think this isn't necessary, but I am stumped...  I can imagine using optional rules for the expression (i.e. either float or int is valid in this expression), but the return type itself requires a specific type.  I am sorry for repeating myself, but I hopefully am clear with what I am confused about.

[Here is my grammar file](https://code.google.com/p/rongo/source/browse/rongo.g)

And the expression grammar section:

```
expr returns [int value]
    : e=mexpr {$value = $e.value;}
      ( PLUS e=mexpr {$value += $e.value;}
      | MINUS e=mexpr {$value -= $e.value;}
      )*
    ;
```

Compare to Bart's:

```
additionExp returns [double value]
    :    m1=multiplyExp       {$value =  $m1.value;} 
         ( '+' m2=multiplyExp {$value += $m2.value;} 
         | '-' m2=multiplyExp {$value -= $m2.value;}
         )* 
    ;
```

And of course our rules are using the appropriate datatypes (int for me, float for him)...

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see the need to let a rule return both a `double` *and* `int`: if you ever need an `int`, simply cast the `double`.

That said, ANTLR rules can return more than one object (or primitive):

```
additionExp returns [double value, int i]
```

which you can set either in the incline code, `{ ... }`, just like the `$value`, or set it in the `@after{ ... }` block:

```
additionExp returns [double value, int i]
@after{ $i = (int)$value; }
    :    m1=multiplyExp       {$value =  $m1.value;} 
         ( '+' m2=multiplyExp {$value += $m2.value;} 
         | '-' m2=multiplyExp {$value -= $m2.value;}
         )* 
    ;
```

In other rules, you simply reference either `value` or `i` from the `additionExp` rule, like this:

```
otherRule
 : a=additionExp { 
                   System.out.println("int a.i = " + $a.i);
                   System.out.println("double a.value = " + $a.value);
                 }
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll play around with both styles (returning more than one, or casting to int).  I still don't quite grok it, but you only truly learn by doing :)

Comment: @Sym,  I added a small example of how to use the extra attribute.