# library to convert string to operations

Tags: java

Is there a Java library I can use to convert conditions into actual code instead of using a lot of case statement for all the cominations?

Eg: "GT value1 LT value2" and it should return true/false based on the input values I give.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to look at ANTLR framework.

[ANTLR website](http://www.antlr.org/)

Just for the headsup:

[ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a trivial task, what you're asking for is a scripting language interpreter for Java.

You could look at [OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/) or the [JSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSR_94) api. These both require fairly extensive knowledge of syntax; so depending on what you want to do may not fill the brief.

However, without some structured syntax you are relying wholly on the structure of the English language - you are getting into the realms of [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outline_of_natural_language_processing).

You could just use a scripting language like [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) if all you are looking for is a way to change behaviour at runtime.

Comment: It doesn't have to be GTE or LTE. I can use '>=' in place of that. That is a much smaller switch block than trying to write cases for all combinations of GTE, LTE, LT, GT etc