# C++ Parsing equations provided by the user

Tags: c++, parsing, equations

I am making a program in C++ that performs some basic calculus functions. In order to create an equation to perform these functions with I am using the following code:

```
float equationone(float x)
{
    return  sqrt(x);
}

float equationtwo(float x)
{
    return (x * x);
}
```

I am wondering how can I adapt my code so the user can enter something like `sqrt(x)` or `(x*x)` and have the functions return the proper answer.

Comment: accept it as string and use features from `std::regex` in `<regex>` header. provided you have c++11 compatibility

Comment: You have to write a parser. Here's how you'd write one in Python using PLY http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html

Comment: @Koushik Writing a parser using regexes is incredibly difficult to get right, due to problems like precedence/unary minus/if you want to define new operators/etc

Comment: @Patashu touche. agreed.

Comment: @Koushik I know from personal experience, I've tried to write one like that, and I was never convinced it was bug free, because it didn't describe a grammar, it just probably worked as far as anyone could tell ;)

Comment: @Patashu oh yes i agree. but writing from scratch is not much fun either :)

Comment: @Koushik Yeah, that's why there are parser generators :)

Comment: Do you really mean `calculus`? or just alegbra and trignometry? It isn't the same thing. If you want to implement calculus you would be better of interfacing to something like Matlab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a so trivial task, because you soon would like to have parentheses, operator precedences and so on.
You need to create a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing). If you want to learn how to create one from scratch, try to look for [antlr](http://www.antlr3.org/). You basically delegate a tool to create a code that is far from easy to be craft manually. Of course you need to learn how to write a grammar definition, but it probably will pay in the future. If instead you need to serve a real customer in a small time with a scripting language, consider looking on something else than c++.
Have a look at [this other reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932664/566608)  on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a parser to break up the string into components (numbers, operators etc) then use [reverse polish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) to process it. The page has links on how to convert to infix notation to reverse polish notation. [LEX/YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) could help you to do the parsing bit.