# Using antlr the AST for java code with switch cases having duplicated nodes

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using ANTLR 3.2 for making an AST for this java code:

**Test.java**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int x = 10;

        switch(x){
            case 1:{
                break;
            }
            case 2:{
                break;
            } 
            default:
                return;          
        }  
    }
}
```

with a Java 1.5 [grammar from the ANTLR wiki](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars/Java.g).

But the generated AST has a duplicated `switch` node.

I want to parse the input file and find the number of `case`s and compound blocks inside the `switch` block for the generated AST.

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.runtime.tree.*;
import org.antlr.stringtemplate.*;

public class Main1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(new ANTLRFileStream("Test.java"));
        JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        CommonTree tree = (CommonTree)parser.javaSource().getTree();
        DOTTreeGenerator gen = new DOTTreeGenerator();
        StringTemplate st = gen.toDOT(tree);
        System.out.println(st);
    }
}
```

AST:

[image]

*(click the image to enlarge)*

Is there is bug in the ANTLR grammar, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Java grammer  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1f-SN9mPxEcu5u_pwRhvtAfgMzENMHP5Z0o1I-Vyei6I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: May be i am not geting you .i have used the same java grammar as on wiki page of antlr which is about 1160 line. then applied same procedure as in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example but with Java.g(Grammar)

Comment: grammer im using http://ideone.com/4NzSTm

Comment: I have used this  [grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars/Java.g).and changes i have done are [here](http://www.diffchecker.com/p3j31qmz)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: this answer was not correct. I misread the rewrite rule and updated my answer to address it.**

Here is the fragment of that grammar that this answer previously referred to.

```
switchBlockLabels
    :   switchCaseLabels switchDefaultLabel? switchCaseLabels
        ->  ^(SWITCH_BLOCK_LABEL_LIST switchCaseLabels switchDefaultLabel? switchCaseLabels)
    ;
```

In this rewrite rule, since the references to `switchCaseLabels` are not written with a `+` or `*`, each will refer to only one element from the rule. Since `switchCaseLabels` is referenced twice in this rule, the rewrite rule will need to contain one of the following to include all results in the AST:

- `switchCaseLabels switchCaseLabels` (this is the form it uses now)
- `switchCaseLabels*`
- `switchCaseLabels+`

I am not sure why your AST contains duplicate nodes.

Comment: if u can help ,what changes has to be made in grammar in order to remove this duplication

Comment: @user2454691 My answer was previously incorrect. I fixed the mistake but now I do not know what the answer to your question is.

Comment: I have used this  [grammar](http://www.antlr3.org/grammar/1207932239307/Java1_5Grammars/Java.g).and changes i have done are [here](http://www.diffchecker.com/p3j31qmz)  . Is there some problem in grammar and how to rectify it.