# I'm looking to extract values from matched pattern in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm using this regex:

> ([\w\s]+)(=|!=)([\w\s]+)( (or|and) ([\w\s]+)(=|!=)([\w\s]+))*

to match a string such as this: `i= 2 or i =3 and k!=4`

When I try to extract values using m.group(index), I get: 
`(i, =, 2, **and k!=4**, and, k, ,!=, 4).`

Expected output: (i, =, 2, or, i, =, 3, and, k , !=, 4)
How do i extract the values correctly?

P.S. `m.matches()` returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to match with a regexp on an expression...you might want to use a parser, because this regexp (when you have it) can't be extended further..but a parser can be extended at any time

for example, consider using antlr ([ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example/))

Answer (score 2):

This is because your third set of parens (the one that you use for repeating expressions) is what's confusing you. Try using a non-capturing parens:

```
([\w\s]+)(=|!=)([\w\s]+)(?: (or|and) ([\w\s]+)(=|!=)([\w\s]+))*
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

Why not simplify your expression to match exactly what you're looking for?

`!?=|(?:or|and)|\b(?:(?!or|and)[\w\s])+\b`

[image]

## Example

[Live Demo](http://regexr.com?35vo4) hover over the blue bubbles in the text area to see exactly what is matched

**Sample Text**

```
i= 2 or i =1234 and k!=4
```

**Matches Found**

```
[0][0] = i
[1][0] = =
[2][0] = 2 
[3][0] = or
[4][0] =  i
[5][0] = =
[6][0] = 1234 
[7][0] = and
[8][0] =  k
[9][0] = !=
[10][0] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything in brackets makes a capturing group which you can later access via index. But you can make the group which you do not need non-capturing: `(?: ... )`, then it will not be considered at `Matcher.group(int)`.