# Add custom attributes to rules

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In [ANTLR: Is there a simple example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example), a question about antlr3, the accepted answer has this grammar:

```
grammar Exp;

eval returns [double value]
    :    exp=additionExp {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;

additionExp returns [double value]
    :    m1=multiplyExp       {$value =  $m1.value;} 
         ( '+' m2=multiplyExp {$value += $m2.value;} 
         | '-' m2=multiplyExp {$value -= $m2.value;}
         )* 
    ;

multiplyExp returns [double value]
    :    a1=atomExp       {$value =  $a1.value;}
         ( '*' a2=atomExp {$value *= $a2.value;} 
         | '/' a2=atomExp {$value /= $a2.value;}
         )* 
    ;

atomExp returns [double value]
    :    n=Number                {$value = Double.parseDouble($n.text);}
    |    '(' exp=additionExp ')' {$value = $exp.value;}
    ;

Number
    :    ('0'..'9')+ ('.' ('0'..'9')+)?
    ;

WS  
    :   (' ' | '\t' | '\r'| '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
```

It uses the `$value` attribute to pass information up the parse tree.

I want to do the same thing antlr4. It looks like the `$value` attribute isn't there any more. How can I add custom attributes to rules to pass information up the parse tree? If that's not the right mechanism to accomplish what I want, what mechanisms are there to accomplish something similar?

---

I tried using locals, like this:

```
/* Store each row in an ArrayList */
row
  locals [
  ArrayList<String> cells = null
  ]
  : partial_row RowSeparator
  {
    $cells = $partial_row.cells;
  }
  ;

partial_row
  locals [
    ArrayList<String> cells = null
  ]
  : Cell
  { 
    $cells = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    $cells.add($Cell.text);
  }
  | partial_row Cell
  {
    $cells = $partial_row.cells;
    $cells.add($Cell.text);
  }
  ;
```

But this doesn't work, giving me this error:

```
error(65): csce322a1p2.g:70:24: unknown attribute 'cells' for rule 'partial_row' in '$partial_row.cells'
```

Comment: `locals[]` are scoped to a single rule. `returns[]` uses the same syntax, but those declarations will be visible to calling rules. Note that neither of these is recommended anymore in ANTLR 4 now that automatically generated listener ams visitor interfaces are available for separation of the grammar itself from other language-specific logic.

Comment: @280Z28: I haven't seen any mention of the listener arms. Can you please give me some documentation for them?

Comment: I meant listeners *and* visitors, but I messed up typing or on my phone. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for "returns" not locals. Also that should work. My test works:

row
  locals [
  ArrayList cells = null
  ]
  : A B
  {
    $cells = $A;
  }
  ;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `locals`, I want to use `@init` and `returns`:

```
row returns [java.util.ArrayList<String> cells]
  @init {
    java.util.ArrayList<String> cells = null;
  }
  : partial_row RowSeparator
  {
    $cells = $partial_row.cells;
  }
  ;

partial_row returns [java.util.ArrayListArrayList<String> cells]
  @init {
  java.util.ArrayListArrayList<String> cells = null;
  }
  : Cell
  { 
    $cells = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    $cells.add($Cell.text);
  }
  | partial_row Cell
  {
    $cells = $partial_row.cells;
    $cells.add($Cell.text);
  }
  ;
```