# antlr 4.2 difficulty using Parser

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I just started with antlr, And I am using 4.2. Easy guessing says it would be like antlr3 in basics. so I followed the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example) question. (But instead of Exp, I replaced Java, which means I want to parse Java) Everything is fine, Until I want to compile the ANTLRDemo.java example.

When I compile that, I get 4 errors:

```
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("some random text");
    JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(in);
```

- first error: constructor JavaLexer in class JavaLexer cannot be applied to
  given types; JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(in);   required:
  CharStream   found: ANTLRStringStream   reason: actual argument
  ANTLRStringStream cannot be converted to CharStream by method
  invocation conversion           (I know what this error is ;-)

  ```
  CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream( lexer);
  JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
  System.out.println(parser.eval());
  ```

to make it short, let's say every line has its own similar error. For example, "parser" does not have an "eval()" method.

What am I missing? I guess antlr4 does not run like 3. Any Ideas? Please consider my beginner status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ANTLR 4, use [`ANTLRInputStream`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/ANTLRInputStream.html) instead of the old [`ANTLRStringStream`](http://www.antlr3.org/api/Java/org/antlr/runtime/ANTLRStringStream.html) from ANTLR 3.

The `eval()` method exists when you have a parser rule in the grammar named `eval`. One such method is created for each rule in the grammar. If you do not intend to start parsing at rule `eval`, then you should replace that call with the name of the start rule for your particular grammar.

Comment: thanks eval() problem solved. But the 'lexer' constructor still expects CharStream, and I don't have one. and the Same goes on: 'tokens' constructor expects TokenSource, and JavaParser constructor takes a TokenStream as argument.

Comment: I made a mistake of importing org.antlr.runtime.*, and my IDE used it. so It is solved :) thanks again.