# Split conditional statement for visual representation .net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a string with a long conditional statement that I need to parse and split up into groups/expressions for visual representation. Here is an example of the source string...

```
($ROOT.OPT_CHAR1 IN ('val1') AND $ROOT.OPT_CHAR2 IN ('val2')) OR ($ROOT.OPT_CHAR3 IN ('val3') AND $ROOT.OPT_CHAR4 IN ('val4'))
```

I need to dynamically parse this string and group expressions together appropriately...

**Group1: - OR**

**Group1-A: - AND**

```
$ROOT.OPT_CHAR1 IN ('val1')

$ROOT.OPT_CHAR2 IN ('val2')
```

**Group1-B: - AND**

```
$ROOT.OPT_CHAR3 IN ('val3')

$ROOT.OPT_CHAR4 IN ('val4')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The evaluation should take into account logical expression Evaluation not only And/Or  but also left/right parenthesis . simple splitting or Regex is not suitable for such a problem. You have to build a parser.

Comment: Agreed. I'm struggling with the logic of creating a parser.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of your expression

```
($ROOT.OPT_CHAR1 IN ('val1') AND $ROOT.OPT_CHAR2 IN ('val2')) OR ($ROOT.OPT_CHAR3 IN ('val3') AND $ROOT.OPT_CHAR4 IN ('val4'))
```

should take into account logical expression evaluation, not only AND/OR but also left/right parenthesis for grouping expressions.

Simple splitting or Regex is not suitable for such a problem. You have to build a parser.

To build a parser, you start by defining your grammars: Tokens, rules, ....

You can use  [ANTLR tool](http://www.antlr.org/) to build/test your grammar and finally generate c# or java Parser and get out of box ready made parser.

Antlr tool takes the  grammar file as an input and generates two classes: lexer and parser

First, you create tokens for each operator and parenthesis:

```
LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
AND : 'AND';
OR : 'OR';
IN : 'IN';
```

Define your variable like ROOT.OPT_CHAR1:  Names are composed of letters and digits:

```
 NAME : ('a'..'z' | '0'..'9')*;
```

Define white spaces:
     WS : ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' );

Finally  create parser rules.

For Details of Grammer structure, read:
[Grammar Structure](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/grammars.md)

Reading simple tutorial for Antllr help you build your parser.

Comment: I have no idea what that ANTLR tool is.

Comment: ANTLR tool  is a powerfull parser generator, read reference in my answer to build your grammar and generate c# parser that can process  text files based on that grammer. read SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example.