# Strange behaviour of ANTLR3

Tags: antlr3

Why does grammar presented in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1932664/5613768 accept expression like this : 2(38) ?? I know why 12*(5-6) is accepted and why 12*(5-6 is not accepted but I can't explain this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't accept the entire input. It stops parsing after the `2` because the `eval` rule:

```
eval
    :    additionExp
    ;
```

matches `2` as a `additionExp` and then stops since the rest of the input cannot be matched.

If you "anchor" the `eval` rule so that it must consume the entire token stream like this:

```
eval
    :    additionExp EOF
    ;
```

you will see an error on your console.