# Use ANTLR v4 runtime within eclipse plugin

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, antlr4

Hello I am new in eclipse-plugin development and I am starting a project to incorporate a translator in an eclipse-plugin and for this purpose I started by using the eclipse plugin [hello word example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example) and the grammar file provided in this [example](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/893547/How-to-Create-Your-Own-Eclipse-IDE-Plug-in), I am able to compile my project and run the plug in but when I try to load the parser I get an exception  'Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/CharStream', I don't know what the problem could be, I have already tested the parser, but outside plug in environment and works fine.

I am also trying to incorporate maven to download the dependencies and run antlr so I added this in the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.plugin.helloworld</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.plugin.helloworld</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
          <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>4.7.1</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.1</version>      
        <configuration>
            <sourceDirectory>src/evaluator</sourceDirectory>
            <outputDirectory>src/evaluator</outputDirectory>
            <visitor>true</visitor>
            <listener>false</listener>
        </configuration>          
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>antlr</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>antlr4</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am using the lexer and the parser as follows:

```
public class SampleHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

        CharStream in = CharStreams.fromString("\"12*(5-6)\"");
        evaluatorLexer lexer = new evaluatorLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        evaluatorParser parser = new evaluatorParser(tokens);

        MessageDialog.openInformation(
                window.getShell(),
                "Helloworld",
                parser.eval().toString());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And the referenced libraries like this:

[image]

I set the build.properties as follows

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
               .,\
               icons/,\
               lib/antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar,\
               lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar,\
               lib/antlr4-4.7.1.jar,\
               lib/antlr4-runtime-4.7.1-sources.jar
```

I read about adding as a bundle in the manifest but I can't find that option in the dependencies tab just the org.antlr.runtime not the v4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the jars to the `Bundle-Classpath`in the MANIFEST.MF.

In the MANIFEST.MF editor do this on the 'Runtime' tab. In the 'Classpath' section click 'Add...' and add the jars, be sure to leave the '.' entry which represents your normal code.

Your Bundle-Classpath should end up looking something like:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 lib/antlr4-runtime-4.7.1.jar,
 lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar,
 lib/antlr4-4.7.1.jar,
 lib/antlr4-runtime-4.7.1-sources.jar
```