# How to create compiler part scanner in java for java programming language without using rejax api?

Tags: java, javacompiler

how to implement scanner in java for java programming language without using rejax API.

Comment: A "parser". Try [ANTLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1931307/antlr-is-there-a-simple-example). Here is a [Java grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java).

Comment: You are a new contributor and welcome, but this not how you ask a question. You should work on your code and put what have you done so far, here. Read the Help Center topics to learn more about what questions you can ask and what type of questions you have to avoid. [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Community will definitely be glad to help you for right questions.